# Removing Thread from an arraylist, stack,queue after finishing task

Tags: java, multithreading

Everyone know factorial right.
I m practicing Thread and class relationship.
My question is getting results from thread class.
If you suggest callbacks, Can you implement callback class for this example.

```
public class factorial extends Thread {
    int sz = 0;
    List < String > ar = new ArrayList < String > ();
    public factorial(int n) {
        this.sz = n;
    }
    public void run() {
        int p = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sz; i++) {
            p *= i;
            ar.add(p + "");
        }
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static List < String > ans = new ArrayList < String > ();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factorial f1 = new factorial(10);
        factorial f2 = new factorial(8);
    }
}
```

Comment: `f1.start()` should start the thread storing the incremental factorial values in the list `ar`. Not sure if i am getting your question.

Comment: where are mentioned stack, queue and callback in this code?

Answer (score 1):

In your main:

```
// Start both threads
f1.start();
f2.start();

// Wait until they are finished
f1.join();
f2.join();

// Here are your lists
List<String> f1Strings = f1.ar;
List<String> f2Strings = f2.ar;
```

However, I can't help myself from codereviewing a bit:

- Class names start with a capital letter (`Factorial`), and should be more descriptive, eg.: `FactorialCalculatorThread`
- Don't access fields directly (like I did in the example above), use getters (`getSomething`) and use descriptive names!
- Also separate concerns! I wouldn't calculate factorials, and also convert to string in one method.